# Does Cloudera Manager need ongoing Root Access?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, cloudera-manager

When installing Cloudera Manager 4, it asks for the root password on a passwordless sudo user to install packages.

Does this account need to be retained, or is it just for initial setup?

Comment: This question should be asked of Cloudera's support.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was put on hold. If running a Hadoop cluster is not professional system administration I don't know what is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is required during the installation and upgrade procedure when using the wizard in the Cloudera Manager.
During normal cluster operation it is not needed.
All communication is done via the locally running agents then.

In fact Cloudera Manager does not store the credentials, after the installation / upgrade it will delete it.
When you upgrade your cluster later you will need to re-supply working credentials to it.

If you are using the manual way of installing / upgrading then it is not required at all.

Comment: As a follow up, my experience has verified this to be correct.